# How to sort an array by group of field value array in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort collection of data by specific values like in sql `ORDER BY VALUES()` but in PHP. I have array like this

```
$array = array(
    array('name' => 'Milk', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Coffee', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Orange', 'type' => 'fruit'),
    array('name' => 'Computer', 'type' => 'other'),
    array('name' => 'Water', 'type' => 'other'),
);
```

I want order data by type but not alphabetically, instead by specific values that I specify, order by type `other`, following by `drink`, following by `fruit`. So the result should be:

```
 $array = array(
    array('name' => 'Computer', 'type' => 'other'),
    array('name' => 'Water', 'type' => 'other'),
    array('name' => 'Milk', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Coffee', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Orange', 'type' => 'fruit'),
);
```

I tried `usort` but I have no idea how to compare with 2 values to achieve that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `usort` like:

```
$array = array(
    array('name' => 'Milk', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Coffee', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Orange', 'type' => 'fruit'),
    array('name' => 'Computer', 'type' => 'other'),
    array('name' => 'Water', 'type' => 'other'),
);

usort($array,function($a,$b){

    //Define the order
    $order = array( 'other' => 0 , 'drink' => 1, 'fruit' => 2 );

    //Compare the order
    return $order[ $a[ 'type' ] ] > $order[ $b[ 'type' ] ];

});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $array );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Computer
            [type] => other
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Water
            [type] => other
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Milk
            [type] => drink
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Coffee
            [type] => drink
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orange
            [type] => fruit
        )

)
```

---

If in case some of the types are on the array, you can do this to make sure that the undefined will be put on the last.

```
usort($array,function($a,$b){
    $order = array( 'other' => 0 , 'drink' => 1, 'fruit' => 2 );

    $aOrder = isset( $order[ $a[ 'type' ] ] ) ? $order[ $a[ 'type' ] ] : 1000000000000;
    $bOrder = isset( $order[ $b[ 'type' ] ] ) ? $order[ $b[ 'type' ] ] : 1000000000000;

    return $aOrder > $bOrder;
});
```

Comment: Hmm before I thought to make table order like that as well `array( 'other' => 0 , 'drink' => 1, 'fruit' => 2 )` and yes it works,, thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. Just make sure all the types are on the array. :)

Comment: yes I checked by adding a code `key_exists($data['type'], $order)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way also,

```
$array = array(
    array('name' => 'Milk', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Coffee', 'type' => 'drink'),
    array('name' => 'Orange', 'type' => 'fruit'),
    array('name' => 'Computer', 'type' => 'other'),
    array('name' => 'Water', 'type' => 'other'),
);

// array_flip turns 0 => 'other', 1 => 'drink', ... into 'other' => 0, 'drink' => 1, ...
$order=array_flip(array('other','drink','fruit'));

usort($array, function($x, $y) use($order) {
    if (!isset($order[$x['type']], $order[$y['type']])) {
        // none of the ids have order, so sort by bare type
        return $x['type'] - $y['type'];
    }
    else if (!isset($order[$x['type']])) { 
        // x does not have order, put it last
        return 1;
    }
    else if (!isset($order[$y['type']])) {
        // y does not have order, put it last
        return -1;
    }

    // both have types, use them
    return $order[$x['type']] - $order[$y['type']];
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

output:- 
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Computer
            [type] => other
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Water
            [type] => other
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Milk
            [type] => drink
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Coffee
            [type] => drink
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orange
            [type] => fruit
        )

)
```